# print a value of particular byte in Array of string in golang

Tags: go

I am new to go lang and I want to print the individual byte of array of string

as in below code I want to print the values 'h','e','l','l','o' once at a time but I am not able to do the same.

```
func main() {
    strslice := make([]string, 4, 5)
    strslice[0] = "hello"
    strslice[1] = "go"
    strslice[2] = "lang"
    strslice[3] = "whatsup"
    for i := 0; i < len(strslice[i]); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("slice is %c \n", strslice[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: `for i := 0; i < len(strslice[0]); i++ { fmt.Printf("slice is %c \n", strslice[0][i])` does the trick.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Go, character literals are stored in a string as a variable-width sequence of UTF-8 encoded bytes. The ASCII code points (0x00..0x7F) occupy one byte. Other code points occupy two to four bytes. To print code points (characters) separately,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    strslice := make([]string, 5, 5)
    strslice[0] = "hello"
    strslice[1] = "go"
    strslice[2] = "lang"
    strslice[3] = "whatsup"
    strslice[4] = "Hello, 世界"
    for _, s := range strslice {
        for _, c := range s {
            fmt.Printf("%c ", c)
        }
        fmt.Printf("\n")
    }
}
```

Output:

```
h e l l o 
g o 
l a n g 
w h a t s u p 
H e l l o ,   世 界
```

Here's an illustration of the difference between UTF-8 encoded bytes and characters,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    str := "Hello, 世界"
    fmt.Println("Bytes:")
    for i := 0; i < len(str); i++ {
        fmt.Printf("'%c' ", str[i])
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
    fmt.Println("Characters:")
    for _, c := range str {
        fmt.Printf("'%c' ", c)
    }
    fmt.Printf("\n")
}
```

Output:

```
Bytes:
'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' ',' ' ' 'ä' '¸' '' 'ç' '' '' 
Characters:
'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' ',' ' ' '世' '界'
```

References:

[Unicode UTF-8 FAQ](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#UTF8)

[For statements, The Go Programming Language Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements)

Comment: +1, it's very important to show the difference between characters and bytes.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach:

```
func main() {
    strslice := make([]string, 4, 5)

    strslice[0] = "hello"
    strslice[1] = "go"
    strslice[2] = "lang"
    strslice[3] = "whatsup"

    for i := 0; i < len(strslice); i++ {
        for j := 0; j < len(strslice[i]); j++ {
            fmt.Printf("slice[%d] is %c \n", i, strslice[i][j])
        }

    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://play.golang.org/p/cHjsvxHu8A). As you see, each `strslice` element is iterated in a nested `for` loop, using its own loop variable (`j`).

In `strslice[i][j]`, `i` is used to access an element of slice (a string), and `j` is used to access a specific byte of this string.

Note that it's *byte*, not *character* - because that's exactly what has been asked. But check wonderful @peterSO's answer if you actually want to print out each *character* of the string - as there's a big chance you do. )